# Working a condition that would match men and women based on their selection

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I am having this dilemma where I am trying to figure out this matching system using parse. Lets say a user selects male or a female, and then selects that he is looking for a male or a female.

I can't just return the opposite decision, because what if a male is looking for a male, or a women looking for a women.

My question is as follow: how do I set up a condition through parse that returns the list of users based on the gender that the user is looking for. In other word, I would want to return the opposite sex of the user, unless they are looking for the same sex

With support, these are the conditions that I have set so far.

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
           query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", currentUserId);
               query.whereEqualTo("Gender","female");
```

Below is the code that allows users to record their information to Parse.com

```
mName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtname);
        mAge = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtage);
        mHeadline = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtheadline);
        mprofilePicture = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
        male = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rimale);
        female = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rifemale);
        lmale = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rlmale);
        lfemale = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rlfemale);

        mConfirm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm);
        mConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String name = mName.getText().toString();
                String age = mAge.getText().toString();
                String headline = mHeadline.getText().toString();



                age = age.trim();
                name = name.trim();
                headline = headline.trim();

                if (age.isEmpty() || name.isEmpty() || headline.isEmpty()) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileCreation.this);
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.signup_error_message)
                        .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
                else {
                    // create the new user!
                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

                    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();


                    if(male.isChecked())
                        gender = "Male";
                    else
                        gender = "Female";

                    if(lmale.isChecked())
                        lgender = "Male";
                    else
                        lgender = "Female";


                    currentUser.put("Name", name); 
                    currentUser.put("Age", age); 
                    currentUser.put("Headline", headline); 
                    currentUser.put("Gender", gender);
                    currentUser.put("Looking_Gender", lgender);

                    currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                            if (e == null) {
                                // Success!
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileCreation.this, MoodActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileCreation.this);
                                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                    .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                dialog.show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Update Based around the suggestions I have kindly received, below is the code. I am not sure if this makes logical sense as it doesn't seem to work now. I have added my comments in between

```
currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
               //It cannot return the current user for you can't possibly match yourself
               query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", currentUserId);
               // If current user is a male, is looking for a female, than return female              
             query.whereEqualTo("Gender","Male").whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Female");
              // If current user is looking for a female, looking for a male than return male
             query.whereEqualTo("Gender","Female").whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Female");

            //if current user is a female, and is looking for a female than return female   
             query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Female").whereEqualTo("Gender","Female");
            //if current user is a male and is looking for a male, than return a male
             query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender","Male").whereEqualTo("Gender","Male");
```

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: I guess I was not clear enough in my description. Hence, my question is as follow: how do I set up a condition through parse that returns the list of users based on the gender that the user is looking for. In other word, I would want to return the opposite sex of the user, unless they are looking for the same sex.

Comment: How about just swapping the "gender" and "looking for gender" around, instead of reversing them?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. So like query.whereNotEqualTo("Looking_Gender","female"); 
but then how would I solve the case of people who are looking for the same gender?

Comment: I have worked it out in terms of if conditions, and have added it under the update section of my initial post. I am still experiencing minor issues here and there, and if you could contribute, that would be incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two steps here:

- get information about the current user ("Gender" and "Looking_Gender")
- find other users that have compatible data

Unless the current user is being updated elsewhere, you can just do the following to get their details:

```
String userGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Gender");
String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Looking_Gender");
```

Now you want to find other users who's gender matches what the current user is looking for, and who are looking for people of the current user's gender:

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
// users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
// users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
```

Of course, you're currently only handling hetrosexual and homosexual desires, what about bisexual people?

To handle this, you would need to change your `Looking_Gender` column into an array and call it `Looking_Genders`. You can then modify the code to handle that.

Change the code that gets what genders the current user is looking for:

```
JSONArray userLookingGenders = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getJSONArray("Looking_Genders");
```

Change the query:

```
// users with Gender contained in currentUser.Looking_Genders
query.whereContainedIn("Gender", userLookingGenders);
// users with Looking_Genders contains currentUser.Gender
// NOTE: no change other than column name is now plural (Looking_Gender vs Looking_Genders)
query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Genders", userGender);
```

I've never actually written any Android code, so you might need to do something like convert the JSONArray to some type of list to get the above working.

Comment: Thanks brother for your response. This was extremly helpful, and I appreciated the clarification provided.